# TestNG dependent method should not get skipped even if one method of dataprovider fails

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

Let's say we have 2 methods with dataprovider in TestNG.

```
@Test(dataProvider = dpA)
testA(String str){
    logger.info(str);
}

@Test(dataProvider = dpB, dependsOnMethods = {"testA"})
testB(String str){
    logger.info(str);
}

@DataProvider(name = "dpA")
public Object[][] dpA(){
    return new Object[][] { { "This test fails"}, {"This test passes"} };
}

@DataProvider(name = "dpB")
public Object[][] dpB(){
    return new Object[][] { { "new test"}, {"some test"} };
}
```

**Given:** The `testB` should execute only after `testA` that's why we have used `dependsOnMethods`.
**Current scenerio:** TestNG skips `testB` even if any case from dataprovider fails.
**Target:** `testB` should run if any one case from dataprovider passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `dependsOnMethods` is a hard dependency i.e., it has to be completely satisfied before a dependent method can be executed.

A `@DataProvider` powered `@Test` method is basically just one way to run the same `@Test` multiple times (of-course with multiple sets of data instead of using the same data which is what happens when you set the `invocationCount` attribute of `@Test` method).

So this cannot be achieved in current TestNG as it stands, without mucking around with the test results etc., and causing un-explained behaviours.

If this is something that you would like to see in TestNG then I would suggest that you please file this as a defect within the TestNG issue page and start off a discussion over this in https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues